# understanding request per second on apache bench

Tags: django, nginx, benchmarking, gevent, gunicorn

I am trying to understand the performance benefit gained by gevent, and wanted to measure this quantitatively. Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) I created a simple django app that has a sleep for 3 seconds in a simple view.

When I run gunicorn with 1 synchronous worker, I get predictable request per second of ~ 3 seconds when I check using firefox. When I open just one more browser, I can see that it takes a longer time ( ~ 3 * the number of browsers I open). The front facing server is nginx.

My view:

```
def home(request,epoch):
    sleeptime = 3
    time.sleep(sleeptime);
    html = "<html><body>%s </body></html>" % str(float(time.time()) - float(epoch) / 1000)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

However, when I run the following `ab` command 
    ab -r  -n 100 -c 100 http://ec2-compute-1.amazonaws.com/

with the following gunicorn command,

```
gunicorn --pythonpath=/home/ubuntu/webapps/testt -c /home/ubuntu/webapps/testt/gunicorn.conf.py testt.wsgi
```

I get the following results:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   7.012 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Requests per second:    14.26 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       7011.750 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       70.118 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          40.53 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       37  837 1487.4     98    3869
Processing:     0 3475 913.2   3777    3890
Waiting:        0 3467 911.2   3777    3889
Total:       3141 4312 1150.1   3870    7011
```

How should I understand the behavior of (3 * browser connections) from the above results?

So, if there is just one worker and 100 clients are connecting, it should really take around 100 * 3 = 300 seconds for the 100th connection (because the 100th connection will have to wait for all the others connections to finish) BTW, if I open up 3 browsers and connect, i takes about 9 seconds worst case, which makes sense I think :). So, my first question is, how come I get ~7 seconds for Time per request in the above `ab` results? I would expect it to be a lot more since only the first 2 connections take around 6 seconds, and all the nth concurrent connections will take n*3 seconds long to return.

When I do not change the program, and just do this following:

```
gunicorn -k gevent --pythonpath=/home/ubuntu/webapps/testt -c /home/ubuntu/webapps/testt/gunicorn.conf.py testt.wsgi
```

and run the same `ab` command, I get the following (!):

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.558 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      255300 bytes
HTML transferred:       241600 bytes
Requests per second:    179.32 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       557.675 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.577 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          447.06 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       33   44   6.2     47      58
Processing:    47  133  74.0    122     506
Waiting:       46  132  74.2    122     506
Total:         80  177  76.2    162     555
```

So the smallest time you'd take to finish a request is 3 seconds, but the above results indicate it take less than a second, which does not make sense.

What am I missing?

I have attached the client that is pinging the view (it is similar, but not exactly, the one listed in the SO questions linked above:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BargePoller</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body{ background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:.9em; }
      .msg{ background:#aaa;padding:.2em; border-bottom:1px #000 solid}
      .old{ background-color:#246499;}
      .new{ background-color:#3B9957;}
    .error{ background-color:#992E36;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function addmsg(type, msg){
        /* Simple helper to add a div.
        type is the name of a CSS class (old/new/error).
        msg is the contents of the div */
        $("#messages").append(
            "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
        );
    }

    function waitForMsg(){
        /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
        When it complete (or errors)*/
       var currentdate = new Date();
        $.ajax({


            type: "GET",
            url: "server/" + currentdate.getTime() + "/",

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
                addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                var currentdate = new Date();
                addmsg("error", currentdate.getTime() + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + " " + currentdate.getTime() + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                    1000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
            },
         beforeSend: function(){
               var currentdate = new Date();
                addmsg("body", currentdate + " <-  sent request");
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages">
        <div class="msg old">
            BargePoll message requester!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```